# Script to write terabytes of data on a memory card

Tags: storage

[image]I was surfing SuperUser while I got to see an answer where a person told that it is possible to write Terabytes of data to a memory card using a script?
Can anyone tell about that script? and how it can write terabytes of data ?

Link to that question
superuser.com/questions/1155458/can-linux-damage-computer-hardware

Comment: Please include a link to that answer here in your own question.

Comment: superuser.com/questions/1155458/can-linux-damage-computer-hardware

Comment: `for ((i = 1; i < $((2**30)); ++i )); do dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M >/path/to/file/on/SD/card; done` writes 1 TiB of zeros.

Comment: Will this work even if the memory card is of less storage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English comprehension and common sense. The terabytes are written successively, they don't fit all at once on the card.

Comment: bro I thought it is a technique to write terabytes of data in a memory card of capacity in GB?

Comment: It was a genuine question... As there might be trick invented in future to write a large data on low capacity data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while :;do
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
done
```

Comment: Will this work even if the memory card is of less storage?

Comment: @HNSingh yes it will

Comment: If I want to write 10Gb of data then show i write bs=10G?

Comment: Can this damage the memory card?

Comment: It should damage the card. This is the goal of the script.